# How can I merge these 3 SPF txt records

Tags: dns, spf

I have 3 SPF records:

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all"
"v=spf1 a ptr include:authsmtp.com ?all"
"v=spf1 a mx include:spf.mtasv.net ~all"
```

How can I merge them all together into one txt record?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The merged record would look like this:

`v=spf1 a mx ptr include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:authsmtp.com include:spf.mtasv.net -all`

You'll have to decide which of the `all` mechanisms you want to use, since you can only have one in a SPF record. I have included the `-all` since it's the most restrictive, and is the one that should be used, unless there is a risk of valid mails being sent from a server not listed in the SPF record.

You should also consider removing the `ptr` mechanism, since it's discouraged to use this mechanism, since it can put a load on the receiving mail-server.

The merged record is also in risk of hitting the DNS lookup limit for SPF of 10 DNS lookups. Since the two first includes currently will result in 2 additional DNS lookups each, the total number of DNS lookups (if the `ptr` is still present) will be 10, which is the limit. So if one of the included records later add an additional `include` the evaluation of your SPF record may result in a "permerror".

Comment: Good answer. One note: `-all` is the best option to use *if you're not using DMARC*. If you are, use `~all`. `?all` is pointless - it's the same as not having an SPF record!